# Newtonsoft json.net deserialization NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I have a simple JSON generated with WCF Rest client, but when I try to deserialize a response I get an error `NullReferenceException` in JSON.Net. I have following JSON:

```
{"Code":-2146232800,"ExceptionType":"IOException","Message":"Msg","Stacktrace":"Some"}
```

And following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class FileUploadError
{
    public FileUploadError(Exception exception)
    {
        Code = exception.HResult;
        ExceptionType = exception.GetType().Name;
        Message = GetMessage(exception);
        Stacktrace = exception.StackTrace;
        if (exception.Data.Count > 0)
        {
            Data = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, exception.Data.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value));
        }
    }

    private string GetMessage(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception.InnerException == null)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }
        const string delimiter = "->";
        var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        for (var ex = exception; ex != null; ex = ex.InnerException)
        {
            sb.Append(ex.Message).Append(delimiter);
        }
        sb.Length -= delimiter.Length;
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [JsonProperty("Code", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [JsonProperty("ExceptionType", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty("Message", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty("Stacktrace", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Stacktrace { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty("Data", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then I deserialize it:

```
const string text = "{\"Code\":-2146232800,\"ExceptionType\":\"IOException\",\"Message\":\"Msg\",\"Stacktrace\":\"Some\"}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileUploadError>(text);
```

And get subj error. Reproduced in new console application, which I can provide if required.
JSON is very simple, why I am getting this error?

Sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/76FJd0

Stacktrace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FileUploadError..ctor(Exception exception) in d:\Windows\Temp\nclgvim3.0.cs:line 28
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectFromNonDefaultConstructor(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: @Nasreddine do you read before marking? I provided a string that is constant, do you think constant non-empty strign could be null?

Comment: This **is** a duplicate of the linked question and answer. If you had debugged the code you would have realized that `exception.HResult` would throw that exception since your `exception` parameter is `null`. Since you're *not* asking "why is my exception parameter null" then the question is a duplicate.

Comment: Voted to re-open to remove 'dupe' flag. This may be a duplicate of *some* question about Json.Net deserialization, but it is certainly not a duplicate of the linked question in any useful way.

Comment: @McKenzieG1 What got solved is OP specific case, not the `NullReferenceException` which doesn't give any info. The answer should provide a way to solve that first and foremost.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add a public parameterless constructor to your `FileUploadError` class:

```
public class FileUploadError
{
    public FileUploadError()
    {
    }
```

Or, you could make it private and use [`[JsonConstructor]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm):

```
public class FileUploadError
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    private FileUploadError()
    {
    }
```

Or, leave it private and deserialize with [`ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeConstructorHandling.htm):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
};
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileUploadError>(text, settings);
```

with:

```
public class FileUploadError
{
    private FileUploadError()
    {
    }
```

Comment: Wonderful attribute, thank you. Didn't know about it.

Comment: This one seems to keep biting me in the backside over and over again. Thanks!

Comment: What's the solution to get a clearer error message? I tried this but it didn't fix it for me, obviously my case is different but we can't expect everyone to constantly share theirs because json.net doesn't give clear errors.

Answer (score 3):

For those tumbling upon this later and since OP's specific case has been solved.

Here is what to do to get a clearer error message when it happens.

Source: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm

```
var errors = new List<string>();

List<DateTime> c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DateTime>>(
    yourJsonHere,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    });
```

And `errors` will contain a list of the errors that occured! Works both for **serialization** and **deserialization**!

Doing so you do lose the context though! So alternatively you can set it to `Handled = false`.

Comment: `using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;` for the `ErrorEventArgs` class